# How to cfinclude independent of CSS?

Tags: iframe, coldfusion

I want to add a third-party banner to my home page. The banner is set up and looks good in it's cfm, but it looks terrible on the home page when I use cfinclude.

I have tried it in an iframe, which seems to work, but I hear iframes shouldn't be used.

Is there a better way to include this 3rd party banner?

Comment: Find the person who said to not use iframes and ask him why not.

Comment: There are reasons not to use iframes in some situations, but none of them that apply to third-party banners. **Use an iframe.**

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually tried to search for sources on why not to use an iframe, and couldn't find anything. @PeterBoughton, can you expand on what situations to not use an iframe, or suggest a link?

Comment: For embedding third-party content they're fine, and help avoid the conflicts you mention. For other things they're likely a bad idea, or at least not the best solution. Reasons are same as non-inline framesets, with the main one being that navigation in frames doesn't change the parent page, which can confuse and annoy users when they try to link/bookmark somewhere but end up back at the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your site's CSS is overwriting the banner's CSS. Try including the banner's CSS after all yours is loaded.

Depending upon how good or poor either your site's or your banner's CSS is written determines your next route if that didn't work.

However, in all reality, iframe might just be the best way to go. I've heard the same about iframe's, but never really seen any proof.